# lucene usage on trec data

Tags: indexing, lucene

Does anyone know of any publicly available Question answering applications which have built using lucene on TREC data?
Thanks

Comment: There are tons of different TREC data sets.  Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Any one of the data sets from the Question Answering track...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this answers your question? http://search-lucene.com/m/A6gcf1wWZdv